# Profile image not showing in circle imageView

Tags: android, android-imageview

Below `SettingsActivity` , which I used :

```
 public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity
     {

         private Button UpdateAccountSettings;
         private EditText userName, userStatus;
         private CircleImageView userProfileImage;

         private String currentUserID;
         private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
         private DatabaseReference RootRef;


         private static final int GalleryPick = 1;
         private StorageReference UserProfileImagesRef;

         private ProgressDialog loadingBar;
         private Toolbar SettingsToolBar;



         @Override
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
         {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);


             mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
             currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
             RootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
             UserProfileImagesRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Profile Images");


             InitializeFields();


             userName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



             UpdateAccountSettings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View view)
                 {
                     UpdateSettings();
                 }
             });


             RetrieveUserInfo();


             userProfileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View view)
                 {
                     Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
                     galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                     galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
                     startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GalleryPick);
                 }
             });
         }



         private void InitializeFields()
         {
             UpdateAccountSettings = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update_settings_button);
             userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.set_user_name);
             userStatus = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.set_profile_status);
             userProfileImage = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.set_profile_image);
             loadingBar = new ProgressDialog(this);

             SettingsToolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.settings_toolbar);
             setSupportActionBar(SettingsToolBar);
             getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
             getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
             getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Account Settings");
         }




         @Override
         protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data)
         {
             super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

             if (requestCode==GalleryPick  &&  resultCode==RESULT_OK  &&  data!=null)
             {
                 Uri ImageUri = data.getData();

                 CropImage.activity()
                         .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                         .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                         .start(this);
             }

             if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE)
             {
                 CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);

                 if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
                 {
                     loadingBar.setTitle("Set Profile Image");
                     loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait, your profile image is updating...");
                     loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                     loadingBar.show();

                     Uri resultUri = result.getUri();


                     StorageReference filePath = UserProfileImagesRef.child(currentUserID + ".jpg");

                     filePath.putFile(resultUri).addOnCompleteListener(new
 OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot() {
                         @Override
                         public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot task)
                         {
                             if (task.isSuccessful())
                             {
                                 Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Profile Image uploaded Successfully...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                 final String downloadUrl = task.getResult().getStorage().getDownloadUrl().toString();

                                 RootRef.child("Users").child(currentUserID).child("image")
                                         .setValue(downloadUrl)
                                         .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void() {
                                             @Override
                                             public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void task)
                                             {
                                                 if (task.isSuccessful())
                                                 {
                                                     Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Image save in Database,
 Successfully...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                     loadingBar.dismiss();
                                                 }
                                                 else
                                                 {
                                                     String message = task.getException().toString();
                                                     Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Error: " + message,
 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                     loadingBar.dismiss();
                                                 }
                                             }
                                         });
                             }
                             else
                             {
                                 String message = task.getException().toString();
                                 Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Error: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                 loadingBar.dismiss();
                             }
                         }
                     });
                 }
             }
         }




         private void UpdateSettings()
         {
             String setUserName = userName.getText().toString();
             String setStatus = userStatus.getText().toString();

             if (TextUtils.isEmpty(setUserName))
             {
                 Toast.makeText(this, "Please write your user name first....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
             if (TextUtils.isEmpty(setStatus))
             {
                 Toast.makeText(this, "Please write your status....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
             else
             {
                 HashMap<String, Object profileMap = new HashMap<();
                 profileMap.put("uid", currentUserID);
                 profileMap.put("name", setUserName);
                 profileMap.put("status", setStatus);
                 RootRef.child("Users").child(currentUserID).updateChildren(profileMap)
                         .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void() {
                             @Override
                             public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void task)
                             {
                                 if (task.isSuccessful())
                                 {
                                     SendUserToMainActivity();
                                     Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Profile Updated
 Successfully...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                 }
                                 else
                                 {
                                     String message = task.getException().toString();
                                     Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Error: " + message,
 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                 }
                             }
                         });
             }
         }



         private void RetrieveUserInfo()
         {
             RootRef.child("Users").child(currentUserID)
                     .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                         @Override
                         public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                         {
                             if ((dataSnapshot.exists()) && (dataSnapshot.hasChild("name") && (dataSnapshot.hasChild("image"))))
                             {
                                 String retrieveUserName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                                 String retrievesStatus = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();
                                 String retrieveProfileImage = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();

                                 userName.setText(retrieveUserName);
                                 userStatus.setText(retrievesStatus);
                                 Picasso.get().load(retrieveProfileImage).into(userProfileImage);

                             }
                             else if ((dataSnapshot.exists()) && (dataSnapshot.hasChild("name")))
                             {
                                 String retrieveUserName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                                 String retrievesStatus = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();

                                 userName.setText(retrieveUserName);
                                 userStatus.setText(retrievesStatus);
                             }
                             else
                             {
                                 userName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                 Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Please set & update your profile information...",
 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                             }
                         }

                         @Override
                         public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                         }
                     });
         }



         private void SendUserToMainActivity()
         {
             Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
             mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
             startActivity(mainIntent);
             finish();
         }
     }
```

Comment: Please don't just dump your entire project here. Figure out what part is causing the issue and post only that part. Not many people will be able to read through all this code to figure out what is the issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add this into build.gradle and tag dependencies

```
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
```

for create Circle ImageView

try it

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/profileuser"
    app:civ_border_color="@color/white"
    app:civ_border_width="2dp" />
```

and for loading image added picasso library

[Picasso Library](https://github.com/square/picasso)

Comment: already done...but not showing